# NonTemplate Function Friend of Class Template

Tags: c++, class, templates, function

On Lippman p656 I read:

> A nontemplate function or class can be a friend to a class template:

```
template<class Type> class Bar {
    friend class Foobar;
    friend void fcn();
};
```

I wonder what all this means. If `fcn` is made a friend it is becuase you want it to access the private members of `Bar`, but how can it access them it if has not got any `Bar` object passed into as a parameter?

Can somebody please enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being a`friend` of a class `X` means the friend (whether it's function, or class) has access to all private and protected members of the class `X`.

In your example, the class `Foobar` and the function `fcn` has access to private and protected members of the class `Bar`.

Now the question is:

> how can it access them it if has not got any Bar object passed into as a parameter?

Well, it can access if it has instance of `Bar`. For example.

```
void fcn()
{
   Bar<int> bar;
   bar.PrivateFun(); //okay even if PrivateFun is a private function of Bar
   bar.PrivateData = 10; //okay even if PrivateData is a private data of Bar
}
```

Just to emphasize the difference, consider this another function:

```
void g()
{
   Bar<int> bar;
   bar.PrivateFun(); //compilation error - g() is not a friend of Bar!
   bar.PrivateData = 10; //compilation error - g() is not a friend of Bar!
}
```

Hope it helps you understanding what it means to have access to private members of a class, and what it means to be a `friend` of a class!

Comment: as I am sure you figure it out, one of my errors in my previous question came from me not being clear on the statement above from Lippman

Comment: Should be `Bar< FooClass >` or something. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Nawaz - I think I am quite clear on what being friend means. It is the whole template thing giving me big headaches. And in this case I had not figured it out that you could create a Bar object inside the friend function and then access it (or having it at the global level), therefore not needing to have it passed as a parameter to the function. I hope I am being clear. Anyway thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a global `Bar<T>` which it can access- just because there is no obvious parameter doesn't mean that it can't access a `Bar<T>`. Also, that's ill-formed syntax.

Comment: Where is the syntax error? Also, did you get my message about §D.5?